# List from elements with the same key

Tags: list, list-comprehension

I've got two lists with the same length (one value for one key):

```
keys_list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd' ... 'z']
values_list = [1 ,2 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 11 ... 213]
```

How do I get from a list of values assigned to the same key?
e. g. for 'a': `[1, 2, 4]`

Comment: Why are you using lists and not a dictionary with lists as values? `{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5, 6]}` etc

Comment: This is the output from another function and I can't modify it.

Comment: `zip` will give you tuples `key, value`, you can go from there, using e.g. `filter` or a list comprehension.

Comment: `[v for k,v in zip(keys_list, values_list) if k == 'a']` but you should indeed use a `dict` so you don't have to continuously traverse these lists

Comment: `itertools` definitely has something for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> [values_list[i] for i,key in enumerate(keys_list) if key=='a']
[1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.compress`:

```
from itertools import compress
list(compress(values_list, [i=='a' for i in keys_list]))
# [1, 2, 4]
```

Or replacing list comprehension with filter:

```
list(compress(values_list, filter(lambda x: x=='a', keys_list)))
```

And lastly incorporating NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
list(compress(values_list, np.array(keys_list)=='a'))
```